# How do you identify similar (but not identical) cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of companies in Google Sheets.

I'd like to spot duplicates where the company names might not be identical.

For example, a company may be listed twice...

1. Once spelt correctly and once incorrectly.
2. Once as Acme Corp. and once as Acme Inc.
3. Once under its full name and once in abbreviated form.

How can you identify these?

Comment: How big is your list? There's no way I can think of to identify every error (How would you find that *Ecme* is a typo for *Acme*, for example?) but there are tricks to help quickly surface some data quality errors.

Comment: It's ~10,000 rows at the moment but would love to be able to repeat the same process for larger data sets.

Comment: You need to decide what constitutes a match. For example, you could determine if 70% of the characters match or something.  You need to determine the logic.  Sheets won't make judgment calls for you simply execute what it is instructed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **Data Cleanup** built-in feature. It's available at the Google Sheets web app user's fingertips:

On the Google Sheets web app editor, click the **Data** menu, then **Data Cleanup**.  This will show a submenu, including three options:

- Cleanup suggestions
- Remove duplicates
- Trim whitespace

Start with **Cleanup suggestions**.

Another option is to look for a Google Sheets add-on at the **Google Workspace Marketplace**. It could be accessed from the Google Sheets web editor.

On the Google Sheets web app editor, click the **Extensions** menu, then **Add-ons**, then **Get add-ons**. This will open a dialog like this:

[image: Google Sheets > Extensions > Add-ons > Get add-ons]

Please note that the **Works with Sheets** is applied. This is done automatically when accessing the **Google Workspace Marketplace** from the Google Sheets editor.